# Smart Cast with hashmap keys

Tags: kotlin, nullable

I'm porting some Java apps to Kotlin, and I keep running into this issue with hashmaps. Let's say I have two hashmaps:

```
var firstHashmap: HashMap<String, String> = hashMapOf("foo" to "A", "bar" to "B")
var secondHashmap: HashMap<String, String> = hashMapOf("foo" to "C", "bar" to "D")
```

And I want to update one if the same key exists in the other:

```
if (firstHashmap["foo"] != null) {
    secondHashmap["foo"] = firstHashmap["foo"]
}
```

Kotlin won't compile the second line because `firstHashmap` isn't guaranteed to have a "foo" key. It doesn't matter that I just checked it on the first line -- the smart cast system apparently doesn't work with hashmap keys. This has the same issue:

```
if (firstHashmap.containsKey("foo")) {
    secondHashmap["foo"] = firstHashmap["foo"]
}
```

This works, but creating the extra variable gets messy in some situations:

```
val newValue = firstHashmap["foo"]
if (newValue != null) {
    secondHashmap["foo"] = newValue
}
```

This also works, but so far I've never had to use the `!!` modifier:

```
if (firstHashmap["foo"] != null) {
    secondHashmap["foo"] = firstHashmap["foo"]!!
}
```

And this works, but the default value after the Elvis operator will never be used, and is just there to satisfy the compiler, which feels wrong:

```
if (firstHashmap["foo"] != null) {
    secondHashmap["foo"] = firstHashmap["foo"] ?: ""
}
```

Taking that further, I tried dispensing with the conditional and just using the Elvis operator, but then it gets stuck on `secondHashMap` not having a guaranteed key:

```
secondHashmap["foo"] = firstHashmap["foo"] ?: secondHashmap["foo"]
```

So then this would work, but that brings me back to adding a default value just to trick the compiler:

```
secondHashmap["foo"] = firstHashmap["foo"] ?: secondHashmap["foo"] ?: ""
```

Is there a better way to handle this, like some way to trigger the smart cast system to know that the key is really there? Otherwise I guess the `!!` option seems cleanest, especially when it's clear from the previous line why I'm choosing to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no guarantee that `firstHashmap["foo"]` returns the same value each time it's called. Smart casting is limited to things that are guaranteed not to change, for example `val` without custom getters in the local module.

You can use

```
firstHashmap["foo"]?.let {
    secondHashmap["foo"] = it
}
```

to only set the value on `secondHashmap` if it was not null.

Comment: If the hashmap is defined locally, how could its values change between the first and second line in my code? In any case, your solution is working for me.

Comment: @arlomedia what will happen if you spawn a local thread that changes the value after 2ms, and inside your if check you've done some blocking call that takes 5ms. Then when you were setting the value, it might have became null, isn't it?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Thanks. I'm not doing anything like that, but now I understand why the compiler is protecting against it.

Comment: The `!!` thing is there for you to tell the compiler no, this definitely isn't null, don't worry about it. You're making a guarantee for something the compiler can't prove itself, and it's on you to make sure that's always true. You're more likely to run into this with `var`s (again because another thread could change the value after you check it, so there's a race condition) and the usual kotlin approach is to go `thing?.let { doSomethingWith(it) }` where the value gets assigned to a temporary `val` (called `it` by default) that's guaranteed to not change. (There's `map.getOrDefault` too)